# PHP MySQL keep selected option from dropdown menu when menu is select from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with my page. I was trying to solve it by a lot of tutorials but i don´t know how to make it work. Simply put i have a database of objects. When i select object, page will redirect to another where are shown all informations about the object. But i need to keep the selected option in drop down menu. There is 110 objects so if i select object number 25, informations will show but the drop down menu wont stay on number 25. Can somebody help me with it?

```
<form action="dbobj2.php" method="post" name="form1">
    Zoznam objektov<br>
    <?php
        include('System/connect.php');
        $sql = "SELECT Objekt FROM DBObj";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        echo "<select name='Objekt'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['Objekt'] . "'>" . $row['Objekt'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Vyber">
</form>
<?php
    echo $_POST['Objekt'];
    echo "<hr>";
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM DBObj WHERE Objekt = '".$_POST['Objekt']."' ";
        $objQuery = mysqli_query($db,$strSQL);
        $objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery);
        $imgRes=$objResult['URLobr'];
    echo '<img src="http://page.sk.sk/imgs/'.$imgRes.'" alt="obj" height="600" width="800"/>';
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $objResult['Text'];
?>
```

First page php

```
<form action="dbobj2.php" method="post" name="form1"> 
  Zoznam objektov<br>
Vyberte si zvolený objekt z menu a stlačte tlačidlo výber<br>
<?php
include('System/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT Objekt FROM DBObj";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo "<select name='Objekt'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['Objekt'] . "'>" . $row['Objekt'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: You select an object than it redirects to anohter page where you choose another object???? Could you maybe be more clear with your question, do you save it somewhere in a db/session? What are you trying to make here

Comment: I have one page called dbobj.php where is only drop down menu and instructions. When i select item in that menu and hit button it will redirect me to page dbobj2.php where is object displayed with all informations about it. The same drop down menu is present here and i need to preselect the object that is actualy displayed.

Comment: Can you show us both the php pages?

Comment: this is the dropdown menu from first page
   ` <form action="dbobj2.php" method="post" name="form1"> `
  ` Zoznam objektov<br>`
 `Vyberte si zvolený objekt z menu a stlačte tlačidlo výber<br>`
    <?php
 include('System/connect.php');
 $sql = "SELECT Objekt FROM DBObj";
 `$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);`
 `echo "<select name='Objekt'>";`
 `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`
  `  echo "<option value='" . $row['Objekt'] . "'>" . $row['Objekt'] . "</option>";`
  `  }`
   ` echo "</select>";`
  `  ?>`
`<input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Vyber">`
`</form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the post value matches the object id in the loop.

`$selcted = $_POST['Objekt'] == $row['Objekt'] ? ' selected' : '';`

If it does `$selected` is set to " selected" and added to the option.

`echo "<option value='" . $row['Objekt'] . "'" . $selected . ">" . $row['Objekt'] . "</option>";`

Comment: Thank you that did it. And it was so simple. I was trying to do it by local storages  like in HTML forms.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can send that value `$_POST['Objket']` via a variable let us say `$selected_value` and in the option tag you can write

```
<option value='" .$row['Objekt']. "' '.if($row['Objket']==$selected_value) echo selected.'>" .$row['Objekt']. "</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a option and click on button then it will work otherwise no.

```
if(isSet($_POST['Objekt']))
{
echo $_POST['Objekt'];
    echo "<hr>";
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM DBObj WHERE Objekt = '".$_POST['Objekt']."' ";
        $objQuery = mysqli_query($db,$strSQL);
        $objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery);
        $imgRes=$objResult['URLobr'];
    echo '<img src="http://page.sk.sk/imgs/'.$imgRes.'" alt="obj" height="600" width="800"/>';
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $objResult['Text'];
}
```